# By-Name-Parameters for Constructors

Tags: scala, constructor, pass-by-name

coming from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646093/need-help-with-continuations-error-found-cps-expression-in-non-cps-position)  is there a way to get by-name-parameters for constructors working? I need a way to provide a code-block which is executed on-demand/lazy/by-name inside an object and this code-block must be able to access the class-methods as if the code-block were part of the class.

Following Testcase fails:

```
package test

class ByNameCons(code: => Unit) {

    def exec() = {
        println("pre-code")
        code
        println("post-code")
    }

    def meth() = println("method")

    def exec2(code2: => Unit) = {
        println("pre-code")
        code2
        println("post-code")
    }
}


object ByNameCons {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val tst = new ByNameCons {
            println("foo")
            meth() // knows meth() as code is part of ByNameCons
        }
        tst.exec() // ByName fails (executed right as constructor)


        println("--------")


        tst.exec2 { // ByName works
            println("foo")
            //meth() // does not know meth() as code is NOT part of ByNameCons
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo
method
pre-code
post-code
--------
pre-code
foo
post-code
```

Comment: I'm using the Scala 2.8 nightlies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because when you're making an instance like this:

```
val tst = new ByNameCons {
  ...
}
```

.. you're actually creating an anonymous class, like in java.
The above code is the same as:

```
val tst = new ByNameCons() { ... }
```

.. while the correct syntax for passing by-name is:

```
val tst = new ByNameCons( { ... } )
```

You cant omit parentheses the same way for constructors as with functions.

Comment: could you give an example of what would be placed inside of `val tst = new ByNameCons( { ... } )`'s braces?

Answer (score 3):

```
val tst = new ByNameCons( {
   println("foo")  
} )
```

Thought it is probably just easier to do this:

```
object ByNameCons {
  def apply(code: => Unit) = new ByNameCons(code)
}

val tst = ByNameCons { // no "new" here -- can't mix traits either
  println("foo")
}
```

Comment: but both variations would not be part of ByNameCons and do not know ByNameCons' Methods, so it wouldnt be possible for the passed code to call meth() if ByNameCons { def meth() .. }

Comment: @hotzen true. I didn't realize you _wanted_ them to be part of `ByNameCons`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why, but it appears that using {} or () when creating the class changes the behavior. Using the following class,

```
class Coder(code: => Unit) {
  def exec = { 
    println("before")
    code
    println("after")}
  }
}

scala> val brackets = new Coder {println("testing")}
testing
brackets: Coder = $anon$1@1af7a03
scala> brackets exec
before
after
```

Now instead if defined another way,

```
scala> val parens = new Coder(println("testing"))
parens: Coder = Coder@dca3ed
scala> parens exec
before
testing
after
```

as desired. It seems as if in the first notation, the compiler is interpreting the brackets as a block to be evaluated to `Unit`, instead of an anonymous function which, when called, evaluates to `Unit`.

FWIW, using ({ ... }) also works fine.

Comment: same problem as in Daniel's Post, the code is not part of the Class and so is not able to access Coder's methods.